# Adding Web Tab in Console app

Tags: custom-button, service-cloud-console, tab

Is there a way you can open the custom tab which I have added in the console app in a new window? currently its opening in the same window but I'm looking a way to open is that possible? I'm aware that it only do `Full page width columns with salesforce.com sidebar`

[image]

Comment: Is that a visualforce tab by chance?

Comment: no its not, its a web tab

Comment: If you can embed that into a visualforce page, or if you have control over the HTML on the timesheet page side, you can add in a little javascript snippet to recognize if its in the console and change the behavior of how it opens. Something like: {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/28.0/integration.js")} 
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
window.open(YourURLHere,'_blank'); 
} else { 
whatever you want to do if its not in the console
}

Comment: i do not have any control over the external site (timesheet).